# How to properly modify libsvm for regression in matlab to get better results?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, weka, libsvm

I want to predict the y = f(**X**) and I have N sample points.

One of the few solutions I am thinking is using machine learning techniques such as **SVM regression** and **Neural Networks**. I have experimented using **weka** however the accuracy is very poor.

I also used [**libsvm**](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/#download). because it has matlab implementation (i dont have the svm toolbox for matlab since my matlab is 2013a). I tested a very simple case using this code

```
 %input parameters    
 training_label_vector = [0;1]
 X = [ 1 ; 2.5 ; 3.5 ; 4.0 ; 5.50 ; 6.0 ; 6.5 ; 7.0 ];
 Y = X.^2.*(2+sin(2*X))/4;
 training_instance_matrix (1,1:8)=X(:);
 training_instance_matrix (2,1:8)=Y(:);

 %train
 model = svmtrain(label_vector,instance_matrix,['-s 3 -t 1']);

 %predict
 [predict_label, accuracy, dec_values] = svmpredict(label_vector,instance_matrix, model);
```

but it only shows only one iteration as some output (I dont entirely understands its output) so i guess there is something wrong.

1. If anyone has some experiences with libsvm in matlab implementation, please give me some light on this matter.
2. Is there a better way to approximate any function, y = f(**X**) which can be highly non linear using some functions in matlab. (splines, least squares regression might not be so accurate especially for highly non linear functions)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code example does not compile (undefined variables), and the Q is generally too broad. Poster lacks a general understanding.

Comment: This matlab code assumes that libSVM is installed in the computer (can be downloaded in the link provided, same reason it's tagged as libsvm).